# Speeding up an app that makes many Facebook API calls

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, memory-management, recursion

I've got a simple app that fetches a user's complete feed from the Facebook API in order to tally the number of words he or she has written total on the site.

After he or she authenticates, the page makes a Graph call to `/me/feed?limit100` and counts the number of responses and their dates. If there is a "next" cursor in the response, it then pings that next URL, which looks something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[UID]/feed?limit=100&until=1386553333
```

And so on, recursively, until we reach the time that the user joined Facebook. The function looks like this:

```
var words = 0;

var posts = function(callback, url) { 
    url = url || '/me/posts?limit=100';

    FB.api(url, function(response) {
        if (response.data) {
            response.data.forEach(function(status) {
                if (status.message) {
                    words += status.message.split(/ /g).length;
                }
            });
        }

        if (response.paging && response.paging.next) {
            posts(callback, response.paging.next);
        } else {
            alert("You wrote " + words + " on Facebook!");
        }
    });
}
```

This works just fine for people who have posts a total of up to 4,000 statuses, but it really starts to crawl for power users with 10,000 lifetime updates or more. Each response from the API is only about 25Kb, but I cannot figure out what's straining the most.

After I've added the number of words in each status to my total word count, do I need to specifically destroy the response object so as not to overload memory?

Alternatively, is the recursion depth a problem? we're realistically talking about a total of 100 calls to the API for power users. I've experimented with upping the limit on each call to fetch larger chunks, but it doesn't seem to make a huge difference.

Thanks.

Comment: is the slowness definitely in the facebook call, or is it in whatever your callback does? have you put some timers in there maybe?

Comment: Why do you need to read the user’s _complete_ posts from the very beginning, what’s the purpose of that kind of app?

Comment: Edited post to clarify purpose

Answer (score 0):

So, you're doing this with the JS SDK I guess, which mean this runs in the Browser... Did you try to run this in Chrome and then watch the network monitor to see about the response time etc.?

With 100 requests, this also means that the data object/JSON must be about the size of 2.5mb, which for some browsers/machines could be quite challenging I guess. Also, it must take quite a while to fetch the data from FB. What does the user see in the meantime?

Did you think of implementing this in the backend on the server side, and then just passing the results to the frontend?

For exmple use NodeJS together with SocketIO to do it on the server side and dynamically update the word count?

Comment: Since the calls are async, the users see the results tally as they come in. The purpose of the app is to see how many words one has written on Facebook.

Does it help if I delete the response after tallying it?

Comment: I edited my answer giving hints about a server side implementation. I think doing this in the browser doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the client side to work with due to IT restrictions.